# post text to all active users

Tags: visualforce

```
public with sharing class chatterclass {
public string entertext{get;set;}
public id userid;
public chatterclass (){
List<User> usersLs = [select Id from User];
System.debug('the users list are:'+usersLs);
}
public void sendtoChatter(){
List<User> usersLs = [select Id from User];
System.debug('the users list are:'+usersLs);
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = '005280000021HMbAAM'; 
post.Body = entertext;
insert post;
entertext='';
}


}
```

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="chatterclass">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
  <apex:commandButton value="post to chatter" action="{!sendtoChatter}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
  <apex:inputText value="{!entertext}" />
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I am trying to post text to a particular user now,but i want to send text to all users,how to achieve please help.

Comment: It looks like you have setup everything for you and you just have to apply `for loop` for `list of users`.Instead of hardcoded id use ID of User retrieved from SOQL.

Comment: how to check whether user is online or not

Comment: List<User> usersLs = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive = true ];using this query,i will all active users,but i want to send text to only online or offline users,

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AuthSession](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) object to retrieve all logged in users.

List userList = [select usersid from authsession where iscurrent = true];
System.debug('##'+userList);

Comment: it will show cuurrent user only active,

Comment: suppose i logged into 2 users,using 2 different browsers,it will show current session's only.

Comment: I have executed above code in workbench by logging in two different browsers with same user. It shows only one record.

Comment: try and check with two different users

Comment: even if u had logged 2 users also,it will show only one user is active